# CSS: Topbar not following the scrolling of the page

Tags: html, css

I know there may be a solution out the for my problem but because its a specific code i decided to make a post and ask for help, so lets get started

I have a topbar (like a banner) that needs to follow the scrolling but it doesn't it stays in one position and it doesn't move
i already tried `position:fixed` and `width:100%` but it adds a little empty space on the top of the page

This is my css code:

```
.topBar{
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image : url("image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This is the code where i load the topbar in the header:

```
<ul class="topBar">
      <li class="topBarItems" style="float: right; color: #fff; padding-top: 15px; padding: 8px 15px; font-size: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $username?></li>
    </ul>
```

[This is my desired result, here the position and width is not set but there it doesn't follow the scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Qjm.png)

[This is what happens when i apply position:fixed and width:100%, there is a white bar added on top and the scrolling works just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m902s.png)

Comment: Try `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;`?

Comment: @JonathanLam that fixed the top but now there is a small white gap on the right side of the page with the width set to 100% and also the other content just goes underneath the topbar (like overlay) it doesnt recognize that it should stop there

Comment: You can try adding this to fix the bottom: `margin-bottom: 50px` (you can adjust the 50px value as necessary). Try removing the `margin-left: -10px` and `margin-top: -10px` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Thank you man. the margin-bottom didnt work but i aded margin-top to the other container where my main stuff were so it works now, also removing the top and left margin solved the gap issue on the right side.

Comment: @JonathanLam this is not related to this post but i didnt feel like making a new thread just for this. i just need advice not code for this. i got side menu with one button m that opens the menu, but when the menu is opened insted of 10 buttons i get 20 like B-B where it should both be 1 button https://jsfiddle.net/3nbmq87f/4/

Comment: Taking a quick glance at the code, I'm not exactly sure sure what the problem is. Might as well ask it as its own question to get the proper insight.

Comment: @JonathanLam there isnt a problem in that code, its just how the buttons are coded, to be 2 seperate, i need some advice at what point do i start where do i go etc so i can make it 1 button, i made a separate thread just for this but im waiting for 90 mins so i can post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.topbar {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
html.is-topbar {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: this has already been solved your fix will also work, but can u help me with this thing:

this is not related to this post but i didnt feel like making a new thread just for this. i just need advice not code for this. i got side menu with one button m that opens the menu, but when the menu is opened insted of 10 buttons i get 20 like B-B where it should both be 1 button [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3nbmq87f/4)

Comment: Since you have loaded the buttons in a different tag, it's normal to show them differently.
BTW, you separate your menu button from the div. And #mySidenav div from left to 0. #mySidenav Button can take the level of your look like B B

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/15416xb1/4/

```
.topBar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url("image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I do not get the white space at the top

Comment: As was said in the comments, this fixed the top but there is still a little white space on the right of the bar, and some of the text gets hidden.

Comment: @JonathanLam im just sad i cant set ur comment as the answer for this thread :(